# Eclipse: How to remove Red Indicator from Persistance.xml when there is no problem when opened in editor?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, persistence.xml, eclipse-2019-06

Following is my persistance.xml which is not showing any error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.2"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="IntegratorMasterdataDS"
        transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/datasources/IasDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection"
                value="class" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Following is red indicator shown by eclipse:

[image: explorer]

[image: eclipse text editor]

Comment: Check the Problems or Markers views. What message do they show?

Comment: It says: The persistence.xml file does not have supported content for this JPA platform.